# Android App Google Spreadsheet form Data Post

Tags: java, android, google-sheets, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I have been sorting through post for days trying to figure this out. I cant get my Android form app to post to google doc's spreadsheet, looking for help can someone please look through the coding and tell me if I have missed something what am I doing wrong here's the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URL;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;


import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class SubmitForm extends AsyncTask<URL, Object, Object> implements OnClickListener{

EditText arrivalText;
EditText assignmentText;
EditText clientText;
EditText departureText;
Spinner employeeSpinner;
EditText jobDateText;
Spinner jobTypeSpinner;
EditText notesText;
Button submitButton;

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsEKRuGCDAg_dE01ZXlyR2VoTHFrWUdTNUVwdnN0R0E#gid=0");

    try{
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.0.single",
                employeeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.1.single",
                jobTypeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.2.single",
                clientText.getText().toString()));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Log.d("RESPONSE", "info: ");
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream inputstream = entity.getContent();
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("YOUR_TAG", "An error has occurred", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("YOUR_TAG", "client protocol exception", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("YOUR_TAG", "io exception", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
    }
}

protected Object doInBackground(URL... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

LogCat:

```
10-29 20:03:44.583: D/CLIPBOARD(28779): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
10-29 20:03:57.636: W/dalvikvm(28779): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bef1f8)
10-29 20:03:57.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28779): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 20:03:57.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28779): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onClick(View) in the activity class com.matrixapps.assignmenttracker.AssignmentTracker for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'submitButton'
10-29 20:03:57.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3087)
10-29 20:03:57.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3627)
10-29 20:03:57.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14329)
10-29 20:03:57.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-29 20:03:57.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-29 20:03:57.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-29 20:03:57.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
10-29 20:03:57.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 20:03:57.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-29 20:03:57.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:976)
10-29 20:03:57.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743)
10-29 20:03:57.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-29 20:03:57.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28779): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onClick [class android.view.View]
10-29 20:03:57.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
10-29 20:03:57.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
10-29 20:03:57.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3080)
10-29 20:03:57.646: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: What is the problem? Your app crashes? Which android OS you are using?

Comment: Yes it crashes I'm currently testing on 4.0.3 and 4.1 I tried the Async method but still crashing. Any suggestions?

Comment: post the code where you used the `AsyncTask`. and crash log.

Comment: O.K. will do I'll post it when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

This is too late, but it might help someone trying to do similar thing,  [this](http://codesmith.in/post-data-google-drive-sheet-through-mobile-app/) article on codesmith details the process you should use to send data to a Google spreadsheet from an android app.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
[Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)